# (Mac) How to create keyboard shortcuts to move individual photos to a particular folder

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, macintosh, macos, osx-finder

I have tens of thousands of photos I would like to sort efficiently. I want to scroll through the photos and individually make a decision as to whether they belong in, say, one of 3 folders: family, photography or trash.

Mac already has a feature where you can cycle through photos in a folder using the arrow keys. Ideally on each photo I would like to have some keyboard shortcut I can press to send it to the folder it belongs to. Mac already has the shortcut "command delete" which corresponds to the menu item "Move to bin". Essentially I would like to create two new shortcuts which correspond to "Move to photography" and "Move to family" respectively.

In system preferences, there is an option to create app specific keyboard shortcuts but they must correspond to an existing menu item, and obviously neither "Move to family" or "Move to photography" are menu items.
(The closest thing I have come up with is using the "Move to..." shortcut in preview, which then brings up a window letting me choose where I want to send it. Obviously specifying the folder every time is annoyingly inefficient. Moreover, I would like to find a shortcut for the inbuilt Finder photo viewer, not the Preview photo viewer. So this is not a viable option for me).

I have come to the conclusion I must need to do something with terminal, though I have no programming experience at all and the search results for my question have been pretty disappointing. If I just knew how the pre-existing "Move to bin" menu item was created, I would be able to replicate the process for my other folders...

I feel like I may have 2 pieces of the puzzle but I don't know how to connect them properly.

On [this website](https://www.macworld.com/article/2080814/master-the-command-line-copying-and-moving-files.html) I saw how you can move files IN terminal:

```
mv ~/Desktop/MyFile.rtf /Volumes/Backup/photography
```

This is not very helpful because this must be done in terminal and each time you must specify the file name. (If only I could make some keyboard shortcut which makes terminal perform the above task with MyFile.rtf being a variable that is determined by the photo I use the shortcut on). The question remains: How to create a keyboard shortcut with terminal?

From [this website](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20131123074223584), I get the code

```
defaults write com.apple.finder NSUserKeyEquivalents '{
"Show Package Contents"="@\r";
"Tags..."="@t";
}'
```

so the `com.apple.finder` is what you use to specify application: the general form is `com.developer.app`. And the "`Show Package Contents"="@\r";` appears to be your menu item followed by the shortcut you want to use (`@` signifies the command key etc). Here I am again encountering the issue that what I want to do is NOT IN THE MENU! I hoped maybe the example used a menu item, but that using a menu item is not actually required.... So I very very naively tried to type some code (which of course did not work):

```
defaults write com.apple.preview NSUserKeyEquivalents  "mv /Downloads"="$@1";
```

Here I'm just trying to move a photo to my downloads folder. `$` signifies shift, `@` signifies command key, so `$@1` is the keyboard shortcut.

Can anyone help?